# Cant start profiling session for VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I am trying to start a performance profile for my dotnetcore app.
However whenever I go through the wizard or I try to start profiling through the performance explorer I get the same message "Object reference is not set no an instance of an object"

But when I try to attach a running process to the performance profiler I can't! The option is greyed out. I think it is because the diagnostics session is running. But I can't disable it.

How can I start a performance profile for my project?

Comment: Maybe helpful: if you switch the target framework to net461 so that it produces an executable, try setting the performance profiler to launch the executable.  I've been able to do that when I can't launch startup project.  Make sure that any supporting DLLs you want profiled are included as targets as well.

Comment: Thanks! I will try. I am using .NetCore 2.1 maybe that is also a reason why. I can get the profiling to work at runtime, but just cant seem to attach it to an executing file.